# JButton Array ActionListener Issue

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionevent

I'm writing a program and I've run into an issue...

I create 1 JLabel array and 1 JButton array.
The JLabel array holds a string, a Club Name.
The JButton array holds a string that just says "Edit".

A For loop then fills each array based on the length of the clubs array, as well as add an action listener for each button.

When the user clicks the JButton corresponding to the JLabel it initiates an Event. In this event I need to find out the value stored in the JLabel that matches the JButton.

Since the event listener doesn't know it's inside a loop, I can't use it.

How do I achieve the goal I want?

See the bellow code.

```
JLabel clubs[]      = new JLabel[99];
JButton editAClub[] = new JButton[99];

for(int i=0; i <= (allClubs.length - 1);i++)
{
    clubs[i]        =   new JLabel("Club " + i);
    editAClub[i]    =   new JButton("Edit");
    editAClub[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            selectedClub = clubs[i].getText().toString();
            System.out.println(selectedClub);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with the current code?

Comment: You can't use i inside the actionListener.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a map of Buttons and JLabels and pass the source of the action in the actionListener:

```
JLabel clubs[]      = new JLabel[99];
JButton editAClub[] = new JButton[99];

//create a map to store the values
final HashMap<JButton,JLabel> labelMap = new HashMap<>(); //in JDK 1.7

for(int i=0; i <= (allClubs.length - 1); i++)
{
    clubs[i]        =   new JLabel("Club " + i);
    editAClub[i]    =   new JButton("Edit");

    //add the pair to the map
    labelMap.put(editAClub[i],clubs[i]);

    editAClub[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //get the label associated with this button from the map
            selectedClub = labelMap.get(e.getSource()).getText(); // the toString() is redundant
            System.out.println(selectedClub);
        }
    });
}
```

This way the Buttons and Labels are associated with each other via a separate data structure rather than just by their indices in their respective arrays.

Comment: Valek, that throws NullPointerException's... I Also had to make the labelMap final. Either way though doesn't work..

Comment: Issue resolved, I used Valek's idea... However, rather then use "this" I used e.getSource().

Comment: @RickyRodrigues Fixed. Sorry, I get confused about the different levels of `this` within anonymous class declarations. feel free to accept if it solved your problem.

Comment: So why not use ((JButton)e.getSource())?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Why bother? `get` takes an `Object` as its parameter.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Why bother with the map then?  The way that the listener is registered, you know only a `JButton` will be calling it, seems like a lot of over header for little gain to me (IMHO)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Because which JButton was pressed determines which JLabel to change. If there was only one JLabel, you would be absolutely right, but there's 99, so you have to have a way of keeping track of which one should be changed.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Ahh, Okay, I can live with that (shouldn't try and read code on you phone ;))